# Changing the Modified Date of a List Item using the SharePoint Client Object Model (C#) with Contribute Permission

Tags: development, permissions, client-object-model

I have a small snippet of code that I use to update the Modified Date of a list item and it works great for users with Full Control permissions.  However, for users with just Contribute access to the site the code doesn't work.  Instead, SharePoint just updates the Modified Date to now.

I did some testing, and narrowed down the specific permission level that allows updating of Modified dates and oddly enough, it's the "Manage Permissions" level.

Has anyone run into this issue? If so, how do I work around this and update the Modified date as a user with only Contribute access to a site/library?

Here's the code:

```
DateTime Test = new DateTime(2012, 5, 4);
ListItem li = list.GetItemById(itemID);
li["Modified"] = Test;
li.Update();
ct.ExecuteQuery();
```